# combine bit in verilog

Tags: verilog, fpga

I've a problem to use the output data from a submodule(encrypt_system) to become an input in new submodue.

Previously, I've successfully generated 228-bits binary (called secret_key) in a system. But then, when I trying to use this secret_Key as an input for new submodule, the simulation shown there is no data generated. I don't know what problem it is.

Basically, my project is to use the secret_key and combine(x-or) with any data (called plaintext_data) to produce ciphertext.

This is my coding:

```
  -------top module-------
    module Communication_security(

   //Declare all I/Os
   Start,
   Clk,
   Reset,
   Secret_Key,
   Plaintext_data,
   Ciphertext
   );

   input Clk, Reset, Start,  Plaintext_data;
   wire Plaintext_data;

   output Secret_Key, Ciphertext;


   //Declare all submodule
   Encryp_System Es(
   .Start(Start),
   .Clk(Clk),
   .Reset(Reset),
   .Secret_Key(Secret_Key)
    );   

   Combine_bit Cb(
   .Start(Start),
   .Clk(Clk),
   .Reset(Reset),
   .Secret_Key(Secret_Key),
   .Plaintext_data(Plaintext_data),
   .Ciphertext(Ciphertext)
    );
   endmodule



   ----sub module to combine the bits (secret_key ^ Plaintext_data)------

   module Combine_bit(
   Clk,
   Reset,
   Secret_Key,
   Plaintext_data,
   Start,
   Ciphertext
    );

   input Clk, Reset, Secret_Key, Start, Plaintext_data;
   wire Plaintext_data;
   wire Secret_Key;

   output reg Ciphertext;

   always @ (posedge Clk or posedge Reset)
   begin
       if (Reset) 
       begin

       Ciphertext <= Secret_Key ^ Plaintext_data;

       end
   end

   endmodule
```

note: For encryp_system sub module to produce secret_key, there is nothing to be changed. It's already done and successfully generated secret_key.

Hopefully, someone can help me. It's just a simple coding but I've no idea on it.

This is the RTL schematics on what I've done:
[image]

Comment: Right now all the thing work well. The problem is at the part of sub module (combine bit). I'm not sure what condition should be used here. The concept is, once secret_key is generated it must be combine(x-or) with plaintext_data.

Answer (score 0):

You have only defined 1-bit wide signals.
I can see from the diagram that plaintext_data is 8 bits wide. But in your module it is only one bit. You say your secret_key is 228 bit so you must make a signal with that width.

I also suggest you start using the new Verilog port syntax. It prevents error as all information is in one place. For now I assume all the other signals *are* one bit wide. Thus you get:

```
module Communication_security(
   input          Clk,    
   input          Reset,  

   input          Start,
   output [227:0] Secret_Key,

   input  [  7:0] Plaintext,
   output [  7:0] Ciphertext
);
```